# Compatibility of colReorder and colVis button in Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

There are 85 columns in my table. I have a total of 4 colVis buttons. So you can think that I divided the columns into colVis buttons. If I replace the column on my 1st colVis button with my 2nd colVis button in the table, the column visibility buttons inside the colVis button also change places. The versions I am using are up to date. It has been mentioned in previous threads but I couldn't see a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sampleData = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    },
  ];
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    colReorder: true,
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'colvis',
      text: 'Main Columns',
      columns: [1,2,3]
    },
    {
      extend: 'colvis',
      text: 'Extra Columns',
      columns: [4,5,6]
    }],
    data: sampleData,
    columns: [
    {
        title: 'ID',
        data: 'id',
        className: 'noColVis'
      },
      {
        title: 'Name',
        data: 'name'
      },
      {
        title: 'Position',
        data: 'position'
      },
      {
        title: 'Salary',
        data: 'salary'
      },
      {
        title: 'Start Date',
        data: 'start_date',
        className: 'extra'
      },
      {
        title: 'Office',
        data: 'office',
        className: 'extra'
      },
      {
        title: 'Extension',
        data: 'extn',
        className: 'extra'
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

link for test : https://jsfiddle.net/gmdy2zLh/5/

Move the name column to the right of the start date column, then examine the colvis buttons. Name column is now inside extra columns. I don't want it to be moved there.

why this is happening?